# Sugar CRM REST API module extension

Tags: rest, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am achieved the login functionality through REST API provided by sugarCRM ,

```
http://<url>/service/v2/rest.php?method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data={"user_auth":{"user_name":"Vsree","password":"0141ffbe5e8d1cbaaeee96b3ca49cc49"}}
```

also updated the login response from

```
service\core\SugarWebServiceImpl.php
```

i am updated the response and its working fine .  but it is a suiteCRM core module , i want to extend the login functionality with out affecting core modules, So how can i extend the modules inside suircrm .How can i achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the login you need to create a custom version of the modules that the login process uses in the `custom/modules` directory.

The authentication is handled by the users module. You could create your own type of authentication by copying one from `modules/Users/authentication/`

and pasting it in `custom/modules/Users/authentication/`.

This will give you a means to extend or to create your own authentication method.

You may wish to simply copy the SugarAuthenticate. Then you can create a custom version of it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for ur reply